Getting serialization plugin error using compose navigation
I need a little help.
I'm trying to use the new type-safe compose navigation. It was working perfectly until I tried passing String arguments between destinations. I'm getting an error displayed on the attached image.

Cleaning the project and invalidating the cache doesn't work.
libs.versions:
[versions]
kotlinxSerializationJson = "1.7.0"

[plugin]
kotlin-serialization = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization", version.ref = "kotlin" }

build.gradle (:app)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.serialization)
}

Some code:
@Serializable
data class PhotoDestination(val uri: String)

    private fun NavGraphBuilder.takingPhotoGraph() {
        navigation<TakingPhotoGraph>(startDestination = CameraDestination) {
            composable<CameraDestination> {
                CameraRoute()
            }
            composable<PhotoDestination> {
                val args = it.toRoute<PhotoDestination>()
                PhotoRoute(args.uri)
            }
        }
    }


Is CameraDestination an object or a data class? You're using startDestiation = CameraDestination - i.e., not an instance of CameraDestination (that would be CameraDestination(), but the static Companion object for CameraDestination, which would cause this kind of error.

@ianhanniballake
Instantiating CameraDestination made my app not crush on startup so thank you!
